# The Jquery script for auto-populating drop-down menu works , but how can I let users still choose options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script below that works for auto-populating dropdown menu from the select tag based on INPUT TEXT .. How can I actually make it so if a user wants to change the option that has been autopopulated , he or she can still change what has been populated in the dropdown menu by the option of his or her choice while still leaving the AUTOPOPULATING feature on , I'd like it to still autopopulate , but in the event that a users doesn't like the option , he can still change it .. Below is the working script for autopopulating the dropdown select

```
<html>
<head> <title> validation </title >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValues()
{
      jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3","stx2");
      jQuery("#ddl_rtumodel").val("both");

  ESNList = jQuery("#ESNList").val();
  if((ESNList >= 986329) && (ESNList <= 999999))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
    jQuery("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
  }
  if ((ESNList >= 660000) && (ESNList <= 699999))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
    jQuery("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
  }
   if ((ESNList >= 200000) && (ESNList <= 299999))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
    jQuery("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
  }
   if ((ESNList >= 1202114) && (ESNList <= 1299999))
  {
    jQuery("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
    jQuery("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
}

  // you should be able to follow the above and add your own conditions  
}

function checkInput()
{
  jQuery(":text").each(function (){
    if (jQuery(this).val().length == 0)
    {
      jQuery(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
    else
    {
      jQuery(this).css("border", "0");
    }
  });
}
setInterval(function () {checkInput();checkValues();}, 500);
</script>
<body>
<form id="provision">
    ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
    ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
    UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
     Unit Model:   <select name="STxName" id="ddl_StxName">
    <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
    <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
    <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
     <option value="trackpack">Trackpack</option>
    <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
    <option value="smartone">Smartone</option>
    <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
    </select> <br />
    RTU Model Type:
     <select name="rtumodel" id ="ddl_rtumodel">
    <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
    <option value="both">Both</option>
    <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
    <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
    </select> <br />
    <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm My instinct is to use events rather than have all those constant background checks going via the setInterval....

Something like this

```
$(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
$(":text").keyup(function(){
  var enteredData = $(this).val()
  if (enteredData == "") {
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
  } else {
    $(this).css("border", "inherit");
  }
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList"){
    esnList = parseInt(enteredData);
    switch (true){
      case ( esnList >= 986329 && esnList <= 999999):
          $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
          $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
          break;
      case ( esnList >= 660000 && esnList <= 699999):
          $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
          $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
          break;
      case ( esnList >= 200000 && esnList <= 299999):
          $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
          $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
          break;
      case ( esnList >= 1202114 && esnList <= 1299999):
          $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
          $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
          break;
    }

  }
});
```

Keeping to tradition, there is a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/tJC4Y/11/)

I think, if it was my project, I'd probably look at making and array of objects to manage the product range and use them to build the dropdowns and events - easier to manage in the long run for a little more work up front.

Comment: No problem - happy to help. Probably should have tidied further with a function to update the selects - rather than all that repetition